# Azure Data Factory -> Using Metadata activity + Filter

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a pipeline as seen in the screenshot below, the Filter activity below looks for **CSV files** + **starting with a pattern** as I specified + **filters out the file if it contains the current date**.

[image]
[image]

**Condition below:**
@and(and(and(equals(item().type,'File'),not(equals(item().name,concat('BBN_TX1_',formatDateTime(convertTimeZone(utcNow(),'UTC','GMT Standard Time'),'yyyy-MM-dd'),'.csv')))),startswith(item().name,'BBN_TX1_')),endswith(item().name,'.csv'))

**My requirement:**
I want to **Filter out/Ignore** any files which are of the current date or greater. I was able to achieve my requirement for the current date but for files greater than the current date I need help, please can anyone advise me on what can be done?

Comment: extract the date from the filename and then use greaterOrEquals or lessOrEquals to compare to the current date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your input! Here is the condition I used and it works -

@and(and(and(equals(item().type,'File'),startswith(item().name,'BBN_PLN_')),endswith(item().name,'.xlsx')),less(formatDateTime(substring(item().name,8,10),'yyyy-MM-dd'),formatDateTime(convertTimeZone(utcNow(),'UTC','GMT Standard Time'),'yyyy-MM-dd')))